# Voice Recording in Talking Character

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have managed recording user voice following the approach mentioned under below link. Recording plays back fine except the starting words that user say. Like if i say "Hello" it only records as "llo" which is because i measure power level to a threshold value where to start recording. Could anyone guide me how can i recover those initial letters to make it smooth ?

[Making of Talking App](http://purplelilgirl.tumblr.com/post/9377269385/making-that-talking-app)

Thanks!